# query params is not decoding

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services

i have this path which will be sent to java Rest from firefox Rest client

http://localhost:8080/rest/resources/grouped?filter=%7B%22boolValue%22%3Atrue%2C%22id%22%3A25%2C%22filterType%22%3A32%7D&filter=%7B%22id%22%3A47%2C%22filterType%22%3A57%2C%22multiValue%22%3A%5B40%2C39%2C37%2C38%2C23%2C24%5D%7D&filter=%7B%22id%22%3A18%2C%22filterType%22%3A89%2C%22multiValue%22%3A%5B3%5D%7D&organizeBy=designation&pageNo=1&pageSize=10

and query params data which is after ? is being converted to 
`{"boolValue":true,"id":25,"filterType":32}` to this which is required but when i send same data from test cases method it is being not decoding . it will be same as encoded

test case method is

```
@RunAsClient
@Test(description = "Filter resources by exp(exp6, exp5, exp3, exp4, exp1, exp2), archive(include) and roles(manager) and organize by designation using page no 1 and page size 10.")
public void shouldFilterResByExpArcRolesWhenOrgByDesigUsingPageNo1AndPageSize10() {
    given().spec(spec)
        .get("/resources/grouped?filter=%7B%22boolValue%22%3Atrue%2C%22id%22%3A25%2C%22filterType%22%3A32%7D&filter=%7B%22id%22%3A47%2C%22filterType%22%3A57%2C%22multiValue%22%3A%5B40%2C39%2C37%2C38%2C23%2C24%5D%7D&filter=%7B%22id%22%3A18%2C%22filterType%22%3A89%2C%22multiValue%22%3A%5B3%5D%7D&organizeBy=designation&pageNo=1&pageSize=10")
        .then()
        .assertThat()
        .body("totalcount", equalTo(2))
        .body("resourceGroups.size()", equalTo(2))
        .body("resourceGroups[0].grplength", equalTo(1))
        .body("resourceGroups[1].grplength", equalTo(1))
        .body("resourceGroups[0].resources[0].name", equalTo("Jayden Brock"))
        .body("resourceGroups[1].resources[0].name", equalTo("Chris Rose"))
        .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

what is the problem?

it is RestAPI

```
@GET
@Path("/grouped")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listGroupedData(@QueryParam(Constants.PARAM_FILTER) List<MapRequestParam> filtersParams,
        @QueryParam(Constants.PARAM_ORGANIZE_BY) String organiseBy,
        @QueryParam(Constants.PARAM_PAGE_NO) Integer pageNo,
        @QueryParam(Constants.PARAM_PAGE_SIZE) Integer pageSize) throws RBaseException
```

And below is MapRequestParam

```
public class MapRequestParam {

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonstr;

public MapRequestParam(String jsonstr) {
    this.jsonstr = jsonstr;
}

public Map<String, Object> getMap() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(this.jsonstr, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
}
}
```

i have got encoded params not decoded params in MaprequestParam constructor

Comment: Can you post your actual method not the test case one.

Comment: ok i have provided